# If I use AWS CLI S3 'mv' command, what type of request is behind that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can't find that anywhere. If I use a command like `aws s3 mv s3://bucket/ <local_pc>`, what type of HTTP request is behind it? Is it GET or COPY?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP request?

Comment: @mrblewog yes, I will edit the post to clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `aws s3 mv` command will issue a:

- **Copy** command
- **Delete** command

In your example, you are 'moving' a file from Amazon S3 to your PC. Therefore, it will be a **download** (`GetObject`) from S3 and then the object will be **deleted** from S3.

If you were moving from your computer *to* S3, then it would be a `PutObject` (upload) and then a **delete** of the local object.

If moving between two Amazon S3 buckets, it would issue a `CopyObject` and then a `DeleteObject`.

Comment: `GetObject` issues a GET request, but you also wrote that will issue COPY and DELETE. I just want to make sure if COPY is behind this request because of the pricing structure of S3. We are moving large number of files so I want to see if 'mv' is using a COPY or GET to do the job.

Comment: If you are moving between two locations in Amazon S3, then it is a `COPY`. Otherwise it is a `GET` or ` PUT`. If the source is S3, then there is also a `DELETE` in S3.

Comment: I am moving from S3 to an EC2 instance. So that will issue a GET and DELETE HTTP requests, not COPY and DELETE?

Comment: That is correct. In effect, the `GET` is making a copy on your local computer. But it is a `GET`.

Comment: @ms12 - Reviewing the source code, admittedly only for about 5 minutes; but one of the `awscli` test cases performs a `s3 -> s3` move to test their metadata copy functionality which explicitly checks that certain operations are called, of these are `HeadObject`, `CopyObject` and `DeleteObject` - so looks like it is a COPY over a GET at 10x cost. Ref: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/45b0063b2d0b245b17a57fd9eebd9fcc87c4426a/tests/functional/s3/test_mv_command.py#L59

Comment: If I am using aws-cli mv command to move a large amount of objects into a folder will it initiate thousands of API calls to aws or just a single API call ? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @AdiLIsmaiL The S3 API does not recognise the concept of 'moving' objects, nor does it understand the concept of 'operating on a folder'. The `aws s3 mv` command will issue at least two API calls per object, since it is performing a `CopyObject()` and a `DeleteObject()` operation on each object (Delete requests are free). When moving a folder, it is actually looping through all objects in that folder and performing the copy+delete operations.

Answer (score 1):

It uses combination of S3 API:

- [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) performs **PUT**
- [DeleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) performs **DELETE**
- [CopyOpject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html)  performs **PUT**
- [GetOpject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)  performs **GET**

Answer (score 0):

Mv is not copy. MV command is used to move the files from one location to another.

It will move a local file or S3 object to another location locally or in S3. The file will be deleted from source and copied to the target path.

If you want to copy, then command is cp.

Hope below link will help you.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

Comment: I understand that it's not COPY, but how is the request interpreted in the backend? If it is interpreted as COPY it will cost >10x more for the operation we need to do. I'm wondering if it uses a COPY or GET in the backend.

Comment: (Moved my previous comment to better thread at the top of this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792045/if-i-use-aws-cli-s3-mv-command-what-type-of-request-is-behind-that#comment132914588_61792382)